# Range-based for loop with auto specifier combined with static_cast

Tags: c++, for-loop, auto, c++20

Imaged that I have an `std::vector` of `std::string`, and I want to convert those `std::string` to `std::string_view` in range-based for loop:

```
auto v = std::vector<std::string>{"abc", "def", "ghi"};
for (std::string_view sv : v) {
    // do something with string_view
}
```

The above code is perfectly valid, but I want to remain the `auto` specifier to do that, how to do `static_cast` in one line range-based for loop like this? It seems like C++20 `ranges` can do this in a concise way, can someone give an example?

```
for (auto sv : v | static_cast<std::string_view>) {
    // do something with std::string_view
}
```

Comment: "*I want to remain the auto specifier to do that*" Um... why? All you're doing is taking a simple loop and making it longer to type and therefore read. `auto` is not a priori good.

Comment: @NicolBolas Cos I am the AAA(Almost Always Auto) activist.

Comment: The "almost" in AAA isn't there by accident.

Comment: `for (auto sv : vector<string_view>(v.begin(), v.end())) { ...`

Comment: I'm an AAA activist, and in this case I agree with Mat.

Comment: Maybe using `auto &` or `auto const &` as the loop variable could be a solution. Unless you specifically need the type to be `std::string_view` this could work.

Comment: @康桓瑋: "*Cos I am the AAA(Almost Always Auto) activist.*" Blind adherence to ideology often blinds people to the most efficient/effective solution to a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that this is a good idea as written, but this might be a useful example of a more general **transform** concept (and an evil lambda trick):

```
for(auto sv : v |
      views::transform([](std::string_view x) {return x;})) …
```

Comment: Using static_cast the lambda reads ```[] (auto x){return static_cast<std::string_view>(x);}```

Comment: @BlueTune: That’s true, but it’s longer and needlessly generic.  (Mine could have `+` applied to reduce instantiations in some cases.)

Comment: @BlueTune: Also, that lambda copies the input strings and returns dangling `string_view` objects.  Not that you can’t write `(const auto &x)`, but I’d consider it evidence for the danger of generic-by-default.

Comment: How is this evil?

Comment: @Barry: Isn’t using the parameter type to perform the conversion without any explicit code at all at least a little clever/evil?

Answer (score 2):

You could, as @Elijay comments, simply create a new `vector` of `string_view`s:

```
for (auto sv : vector<string_view>(v.begin(), v.end()))
```

but this kind of defeats the whole purpose of using `string_view` in the first place: to avoid copying.

It also, as commented below, kind of defeats the whole purpose of `auto`: to avoid unnecessarily restating type information. Here the type is being introduced for the first time so *must* be explicitly stated. Why not right up front in plain view?

Less verbose and using `string_view` as intended is where you started:

```
for (string_view sv : v)
```

Comment: ..and defeats the purpose of `auto` to avoid spelling out the type explicitly

Comment: You're going to have to spell out the type name *somewhere*. I don't see how you can avoid saying the type seeing as it's not the default.

Comment: @Barry I most certain am not suggesting that at all. How can I make that clearer?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<std::string>{"abc", "def", "ghi"};
  for (auto sv : std::vector<std::string_view>(v.begin(), v.end())) {
    // use sv ...
  }
}
```

However note that creating a whole new vector is not at all recommended. It allocates memory again and causes a lot of unnecessary overhead. Besides, you have to spell the type somewhere anyway, so `auto` doesn't have any advantages at all here. The Right Thing<sup>TM</sup> to do is specifying the type name explicitly and not using `auto`.

Comment: 1) This is allocating, which is a huge and totally unnecessary overhead. 2) Especially with types like `vector`, when you're not using the initializer list ctor, prefer `()`. You should be wary of `{}` in these cases. Consider what just `vector{v.begin(), v.end()}` means, for instance.

Comment: @Barry 1) I know creating a whole new vector is quite unnecessary and explicitly  specifying the type is the best way to go and I did mention that in the answer. 2) Thank you for criticism about the brace choice. Fixed it. But in any case I think template-type detection for complex types like `std::vector` should never be used. Just specifying `<Type>` explicitly can save a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators is a good customization point, unfortunately it requires quite some boilerplate:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

template <typename T>
struct container_view {
    const T& container;
    container_view(const T& t) : container(t) {}
    struct iterator{
        typename T::const_iterator base;
        iterator(const typename T::const_iterator& it) : base(it) {}
        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) { return base != other.base; }
        iterator& operator++() { ++base; return *this; }
        std::string_view operator*() { return {*base}; } 

        //    ^--- string_view

    };
    iterator begin() { return {container.begin()};}
    iterator end() { return {container.end()};}    
};

int main (){
    auto v = std::vector<std::string>{"abc", "def", "ghi"};

    //    v--- auto

    for (auto sv : container_view(v)) {
        std::cout << sv << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguably more/less succinct. Opinions will vary.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<std::string>{"abc", "def", "ghi"};

    using namespace ranges;

    auto as_string_view = views::transform([](auto&& x) { return std::string_view(x); });

    for (auto sv : v | as_string_view) {
        std::cout << sv << '\n';
    } 
}
```